# Go: pausing a goroutine

Tags: select, go, goroutine

I have the following code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    ws := make(chan int)
    go looper(ws)
    time.Sleep(3 * time.Second)
    ws <- 0
    time.Sleep(3 * time.Second)
    ws <- 1
    time.Sleep(3 * time.Second)
}

func looper(ws chan int) {
    i := 0
    state := 1
    for {
        time.Sleep(1)  // COMMENT OUT?
        select {
        case state = <- ws:
            fmt.Println("State changed!")
        default:
            if state == 1 {
                fmt.Println("Current: ", i)
                i++
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I tried to implement: `looper()` prints and increments `i` for 3 seconds, then waits 3 seconds, then prints again for 3 seconds. And in fact, this is just what my code does:

```
Current: 0
...
Current: X
State changed!
State changed!
Current: X + 1
...
Current: Y
```

My question is: why, if I comment out the `time.Sleep(1)` inside `for` loop, the program prints this:

```
Current: 0
...
Current: X
State changed!
```

and then just never quits being stuck in a loop, not even getting to `ws <- 1`? I don't understand.

Comment: weird, tried to comment/uncomment that line, and both get 2 'State changed!'

Comment: Your code works as expected. What version of Go are you using, and what are you setting GOMAXPROC to? If you're going to have what is essentially a busy loop, you need at least GOMAXPROCS=2 to be able to schedule it reliably.

Comment: @JimB Thanks, I will try to change this value at home.

Comment: I'm guessing you're also using an old version of go, since the selects should have provided more preemption points. You could make what you're currently running more reliable by replacing the 1 nanosecond sleep with a `runtime.Gosched()`

Comment: @JimB `runtime.Gosched()` worked perfectly. Thank you again!